# "Could not load file or assembly" Error Com-Enabled .Net Assembly

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com

Currently, I am stuck with a classic asp project, that needs to call a .Net Assembly.  It was working, until the customer had to wipe their server.  I was able to reregister the .Net Assembly, but I get this error during runtime:

> MyDll error '80070002'
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the asp code, not sure if it will help.

```
set Inst = Server.CreateObject("MyDll.AddressValidator")

If Inst.ProcessAddress(Adr1,City, State, Zip) Then
   'code
End If
```

Comment: Is any of the information here useful? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: John, it did help.  I hadn't thought I would need gacutil to load the Newtonsoft json dll, but it worked!!!

Comment: If you've solved the problem you're allowed to answer your own question, you worked it out, and it's useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was to register the Newtonsoft dll in the GAC, using the gacutil executable.  I thought it was enough to register my dll with regasm.exe and have the Newtonsoft dll in the same directory.  Thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087551/john) prompting me with a link.  I had read it before, but decided to stop, breath, and follow all the steps.

Wade